# Problema con clase abstracta e interfaces

Tags: java, poo, clase, clase-abstracta

He escrito el código de las clases, pero no me sale.

Específicamente, en los métodos `CalularSaldoCC` y `CalularSaldoCA` sale error de que no reconoce `MontoApertura`. Además, no sé si moverlo a `CuantaBancaria` o dejarlos allí.

[image: Problema Java]

**Clase abstracta `CuentaBancaria`**

```
public abstract class CuentaBancaria
{
    private String IdCta;
    private String IdClie;
    private float MontoApertura;
    private float Saldo;

    public CuentaBancaria(String IdCta, String IdClie, float MontoApertura, float Saldo) {
        this.IdCta = IdCta;
        this.IdClie = IdClie;
        this.MontoApertura = MontoApertura;
        this.Saldo = Saldo;
    }
    public String getIdClie()
    {        return IdClie;     }
    public void setIdClie(String IdClie)
    {        this.IdClie = IdClie;    }
    public String getIdCta()
    {        return IdCta;    }
    public void setIdCta(String IdCta)
    {        this.IdCta = IdCta;    }
    public float getMontoApertura()
    {        return MontoApertura;    }
    public void setMontoApertura(float MontoApertura)
    {        this.MontoApertura = MontoApertura;    }
    public float getSaldo()
    {        return Saldo;    }
    public void setSaldo(float Saldo)
    {        this.Saldo = Saldo;    }    
    public abstract float CuentaBancaria(String IdCta, String IdClie, float MontoApertura);
    public void MostrarDatos()    {
        System.out.println("Codigo Cliente: " + getIdClie() + "\nCodigo Cuanta Bancaria: " + getIdCta()
                 + "\nMonto Apertura: " + getMontoApertura() + "\nSaldo: " + getSaldo());    
    }      
}
```

**Clase `CuentaCorriente`**

```
public abstract class CuentaCorriente extends CuentaBancaria implements ICCorriente
{
    private double InteresProrrateado;

    public CuentaCorriente(double InteresProrrateado, String IdCta, String IdClie, float MontoApertura, float Saldo) {
        super(IdCta, IdClie, MontoApertura, Saldo);
        this.InteresProrrateado = InteresProrrateado;
    }

    public double getInteresProrrateado() {
        return InteresProrrateado;
    }

    public void setInteresProrrateado(double InteresProrrateado) {
        this.InteresProrrateado = InteresProrrateado;
    }    

    public float CuentaBancaria(String IdCta, String IdClie, float MontoApertura)
    {
        return MontoApertura;
    }

    @Override
    public double CalculaSaldoCC()
    {
        return (MontoApertura + (MontoApertura*InteresProrrateado));
    }
}
```

**Clase `CuentaAhorros`**

```
public class CuentaAhorros extends CuentaBancaria implements ICAhorros
{
    private double InteresMensual;
    private int CantMeses;

    public CuentaAhorros(double InteresMensual, int CantMeses, String IdCta, String IdClie, float MontoApertura, float Saldo) {
        super(IdCta, IdClie, MontoApertura, Saldo);
        this.InteresMensual = InteresMensual;
        this.CantMeses = CantMeses;
    }

    public int getCantMeses() {
        return CantMeses;
    }

    public void setCantMeses(int CantMeses) {
        this.CantMeses = CantMeses;
    }

    public double getInteresMensual() {
        return InteresMensual;
    }

    public void setInteresMensual(double InteresMensual) {
        this.InteresMensual = InteresMensual;
    }


    @Override
    public double CalculaSaldoCA()
    {
        return (MontoApertura + (CantMeses*InteresMensual));
    }

}
```

**Interfaces**

```
public interface ICCorriente
{
    double CalculaSaldoCC();
}

public interface ICAhorros
{
    double CalculaSaldoCA ();    
}
```

Comment: Necesitas hacer una pregunta específica. ¿Hay algo específicamente con el cual necesitas ayuda? ¿Tal vez hay algo en tu programa que te está dando errores? Si es el caso, por favor incluye los detalles pertinentes al respecto.

Comment: Hola ssta, los metodos CalularSaldoCC//CA sale error no reconoce MontoApertura. Ademas nose si moverlo a CuantaBancaria o dejarlos ahi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> En los métodos `CalularSaldoCC` y `CalularSaldoCA` sale error no reconoce `MontoApertura`. Además no sé si moverlo a `CuantaBancaria` o dejarlos allí.

La variable `MontoApertura`

```
private float MontoApertura;
```

... es privada en la clase `CuantaBancaria`, por lo que no puedes acceder a ella en las clases `CuentaCorriente` y `CuentaAhorros`, aun si estas son clases que heredan de la clase `CuantaBancaria`.

Sin embargo, la clase `CuantaBancaria` incluye los métodos propiedades `getMontoApertura` y `setMontoApertura`

```
public float getMontoApertura()
{        return MontoApertura;    }
public void setMontoApertura(float MontoApertura)
{        this.MontoApertura = MontoApertura;    }
```

... que son públicas y que son capaces de leer y escribir a la variable `MontoApertura`. Puedes usar estos métodos en vez de intentar manipular la variable `MontoApertura` directamente.

```
@Override
public double CalculaSaldoCC()
{
    return (this.getMontoApertura() + (this.getMontoApertura()*this.InteresProrrateado));
}

// ...

@Override
public double CalculaSaldoCA()
{
    return (this.getMontoApertura() + (CantMeses*InteresMensual));
}
```

Comment: sstan gracias, por tu apoyo ya pude terminar el programa.